# Eigenfunctions of non-uniform convolution

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-analysis, convolution

Consider a non-uniform ("generalized"?) convolution operator:

$$
A_h[f](t) = \int f(x)h(x,t)dx
$$

I would like determine the eigenfunctions. In the "stationary" case where $h(x,t) = h(x-t)$ we have the standard convolution, whose eigenfunctions are the complex exponentials $e^{ikt}$ and eigenvalues are the Fourier transform of $h$.

Obviously this is a pretty open-ended problem. I'm specifically interested in the case that the convolution is just a spatially-varying Gaussian blur, so:

$$
h(x,t) = \exp\left[-\frac{(x-t)^2}{2\sigma_x^2}\right]
$$

That is, the width of the blur depends on location. How can we compute the eigenfunctions, or equivalently diagonalize the non-uniform convolution operator matrix? I would guess that we could use wavelets (since waves work in the stationary case) but I suspect we need to impose limits on how quickly $\sigma_x$ changes (i.e. making it "locally stationary").

I would just add that a partial solution, or a link to a related solution, or even just an outline, would be really helpful!

Comment: Would you mind writing out $h(x,t)$ explicitly (possibly in 1D?) for your example? It's a bit unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @CameronWilliams thanks for your reply. I wrote out h(x,t) in 1D, is that any clearer?

Comment: This is still just a convolution in this example as far as I can tell.

Comment: @CameronWilliams it's a spatially varying convolution. See that there's sigma_x instead of sigma. So the width can vary.

Comment: Oh shoot. I did not realize that. There are so very few general techniques for solving integral equations - many of which happen to involve turning them into differential equations. Much of this, as said below, is "existence" and "numerical approximation."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very atypical to be able to compute the eigenfunctions of a general integral operator explicitly.  What is special about convolution operators is that they exhibit translation symmetry, which is why periodic functions "diagonalize" them.  Wavelets are known to *almost* diagonalize certain kinds of nonstationary operators - this is discussed in [Meyer's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521794730) on wavelets and Calderon-Zygmund theory.

If your operator doesn't have some really nice symmetries (translational, rotational, etc), then you're pretty much stuck with making general existence claims, which fall under the heading of [spectral theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theory).  If you want to try and estimate the eigenvalues/eigenfunctions, you'll usually need to resort to numerical techniques.

Comment: That's helpful, thank you. I was hoping that wavelets would diagonalize it if sigma were restrained to only change slowly. The limit would be that at sigma being constant you would only need frequency terms, not time. This is just my intuition though.

Comment: It's good intuition, and wavelets are a great tool to use for nonstationary things, but they won't diagonalize exactly.

Comment: That may be good enough--my goal is ultimately to transform the non-stationary covariance matrix into something sparse and thus easily invertible.

Comment: Also do you happen to know a more...accessible source than Meyer's book for understanding the almost-diagonalizability of some transforms with wavelets? Thanks.

Comment: Ah, yeah...Meyer is a bit rough for the non harmonic analyst. I can't think of anything right now...I think Mallat's Wavelet Tour talks about this a little bit, and Daubechies 10 Lectures as well.  How rigorous do you want to get?

Comment: Well, I'm essentially completely new to wavelets. And I come from physics. I'm not after complete rigor, I'm just lazily trying to get as quickly as possible to simulating a Gaussian process that has the covariance created by that convolution. So I'm hoping that transforming to the wavelet domain will make all my calculations much faster :)